# 1:1 NAT or MultiIP for WAN implementation on OpenWRT NFTABLES (fw4)

Tags: firewall, nat, openwrt, nftables, dnat

I would like to configure 1:1 NAT for my ISP modem connected to my OpenWRT WAN interface.

The modem IP address is 10.70.70.1 and I want to map it on my OpenWRT LAN bridge (192.168.64.0/24) with IP address 192.168.64.171.

My DHCP range for the LAN interface is starting from 50 and maximum number of ip assignments is 50 devices.
(192.168.64.50-192.168.64.100)

Since the modem will get a static uniques 1:1 ip address outside of the LAN DHCP range IP address I persume it will never make IP address conflict with other devices.

Having that said I followed the guide at https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/multiple_public_ips and it seems it is not compatible with NFTABLES or fw4 implementation that comes with the latest OpenWRTs.

I would like to know what is the fw4 (NFTABLES) equivalent of the implementation of the guide link or how can I implement my desired configuration on the OpenWRT router?

Comment: I'm sorry but home and enduser related equipment is not on topic for serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi like other questions on this website I can see many have asked similar and related questions, especially I do find answer to this question might be helpful and beneficial to others with minor adpotation.
I have to emphasis I am not the only person who owns the OpenWRT router and OpenWRT is not limited to home users while many might find my desired configurations useful for them too.
I do find this website more active then OpenWRT since it is not the only linux based OS that implemets NFTABLES.

Comment: openwrt is not a business environment. please take care about [what is on topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). eve some exists doesn't mean that you are on the right website ;)

Comment: Aaa...what the problem is i cant figure out